# Reading from a file into the *argv[] array

Tags: c, program-entry-point, argv

I try to convert a Linux program in C to DOS. Since the DOS command line allows only 128 bytes I try to read in the arguments from a file. This file has one line for each argument.

So I read in the arguments from the file into a string array and want to override the *argv[] address with the address of my string array.

But I get confused with pointers to pointers. What shall I do to correctly override the *argv[] address in my function?

This program is called with "argvtest.exe commands.dat"

Here is my test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void read_cmd_file(int *argc,char *argv[]){

    if (*argc != 2 ) return;

    char buf[256];
    char arguments[30][256];
    int line_nr=0,i;

    FILE *fp=(FILE *) NULL;

    /* open the file */
    fp=fopen(argv[1],"r");
    if (fp == (FILE *) NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open command file: %s",argv[1]);
        return;
    }

    while (fgets(buf,sizeof(buf)-1,fp) && !feof(fp))
    {

        line_nr++;
        strcpy(arguments[line_nr],buf);
        //printf("Argument read: %s\n",buf);
    }

    if (fp != (FILE *) NULL)
        (void) fclose(fp);

    for (i=1;i<=line_nr;i++) printf("%d,%s\n",i,arguments[i]);

    *argv=&arguments[0][0];
    *argc=line_nr;

    return;

}

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    int i;
    read_cmd_file(&argc,argv);
    printf("argc=%d\n",argc);
    for (i=0;i<argc;i++) printf("%d,%s\n",i,argv[i]);
}
```

Comment: Why on earth would you do that?? Also consider that `argv` has a fixed size and if you don't provide an equal number of bytes, your program might break...

Comment: Why are you casting null pointers? That's unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you should do. First, you will need a pointer to pointer to pointer:

```
void read_cmd_file(int *argc,char ***argv)
{
    ...
    fp=fopen((*argv)[1],"r");
    ...
    *argv = result;
}

...
read_cmd_file(&argc,&argv);
```

Then, you shall never try to return a reference to a local variable from a function: in your code

```
*argv=&arguments[0][0];
```

is a sign of evil and shall not be used...

Instead, you will have to allocate memory in the function, and then release it after use. Something like:

```
void read_cmd_file(int *argc,char ***argv)
{
    char **arguments;

    ...
    arguments = calloc(30, sizeof(*arguments)); // 30 args
    ...
    while (fgets(buf,sizeof(buf)-1,fp) && !feof(fp))
    {
        line_nr++;
        arguments[line_nr] = strdup(buf); // allocates memory on heap
    }
    ...
    *argv=arguments;
}

...
int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    int i;
    read_cmd_file(&argc,&argv);
    for (i=0;i<argc;i++) printf("%d,%s\n",i,argv[i]);
    ...
    for (i = 0; i <argc; i++)
    {
        free(argv[i]);
    }
    free(argv);
}
```

Comment: I am amazed that you can do this correctly without compiling this code.